# Type 'Alias[]' has no properties in common with type 'Alias'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express

I got an error:

> Type 'Alias[]' has no properties in common with type 'Alias'

This is my Alias

```
  alias: Alias = {
    id: 0,
    domain_id: 0,
    source: '',
    destination: ''
  };
```

This is my Alias model

```
export interface Alias {
    id?: number;
    domain_id?: number;
    source?: string;
    destination?: string;
}
```

and I go error here in line with this.alias = res

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const params = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
    console.log('parms '+params);
    if (params.id) {
      this.aliasesService.getAlias(params.id).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.alias = res;
          this.edit = true;
        },
        err => console.error(err)
      );
    }
  }
```

And there is my service

```
getAlias(id: string): Observable<Alias[]> {
    return this.http.get<Alias[]>(`${this.API_URI}/aliases/${id}`);
  }
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What does `this.aliasesService.getAlias(params.id)` return?

Comment: you are trying to reference an array of aliases in a property of type alias. either change the property to an array, or have the backend send back a single alias

Comment: alias must be with type Alias[] not  Alias

Comment: Please see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159035/get-array-from-response-instead-of-object#comment104542867_59159035) on [your last question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59159035/157247). Names matter. Using `alias` when you mean `aliases` is a problem you need to fix. Similarly, I strongly recommend using a meaningful name, not `res`, for the parameter of your `observe` callback. Make sure it matches what's being provided (`alias` for one alias, `aliases` for more than one). It will help you avoid these problems.

Comment: @NicholasK it returns a single Alias

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
getAlias(id: string): Observable<Alias[]> {
  return this.http.get<Alias[]>(`${this.API_URI}/aliases/${id}`);
}
```

To this:

```
//I guess this api returns a single Alias
getAlias(id: string): Observable<Alias> {
  return this.http.get<Alias>(`${this.API_URI}/aliases/${id}`);
}
```

**EDIT:**

By the way, you can simplify your code like this

From:

```
alias: Alias = {
  id: 0,
  domain_id: 0,
  source: '',
  destination: ''
};
```

To:

```
alias: Alias = {} as Alias; //it's the same thing
```

Comment: it works but now "res"  returns object Object instead of array. So I can't display it

Comment: @MarrZZ show me your html code and console.log the "res"